# how to set 404 Status code for single route in Angular application?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my Angular application, I want to set a `404 status` code (In-network request) for my wildcard route.

I tried setting manually `meta tag` for the same but no luck.

We are using `Prerender.io` and `Lambda` function, anyway, we can take help any of these?

PS: I am not using `SSR` and not supposed to implement the same.

More information on [this thread](https://twitter.com/erpardeepjain/status/1390273014277701634?s=20)

Comment: Is [this](https://skynix.co/resources/how-to-set-404-status-code-in-angular) your answer?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi No, because they are using Angular universal